24.04 weird gamepad mappings
unbutu 24.04, kernel 6.8.0-36-generic x86_64, on a dell g15 5511.
all wired and bluetooth controllers are having the same issue; the button mappings are strange, the right stick never works, the buttons are swapped around, the bumpers do not work, etc. they're mapped so strangely they're unusable. i have tried two wired nintendo switch controllers, a set of joycons, both bluetooth and usb for an xbox one controller and i plan to try my roommates ps5 controller later but i assume it's going to give the same results.
i did not have this issue previously. my joycons always worked fine as well as one of the wired controllers. i'm assuming the issue started when i purged nvidia from my laptop. i couldn't boot after updating my drivers, so i had to purge nvidia but this also removed my ability to connect to wifi (completely as if there wasn't an adapter) and i had to fix that. i thought perhaps something else got removed which affected my controllers, but maybe not.
i can't like edit the mapping using steam or anything else either because some of the buttons aren't recognized at all, like the bottom button (a on xbox) never works.
i have already tried xboxdrv for the xbox controller and it isn't recognized even though it shows on any gamepad tester website. (everytime i google this issue i repeatedly find that solution)

Which browser did you use for gamepad tester?

Firefox. i have the same issues and response from the gamepad on steam and a couple of playstation emulators as well.
